# How to access specific anchor class names in android webview?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am creating a webview app but issue is all the links are opening in same app. I want to open other website links in external browser for this purpose i have set class name "external" for the links that i want to open in external browser. Issue is how to access these classes in android to open these links in external browser?

```
<a href="www.otherdomain.com" class="external">External Browser</a>
```